# How to pass parameters to reactjs app hooked in as webpart of a site?

Tags: html, reactjs

I built a reactjs app which i want to use as simple webpart of my site.
Means my site can have multiple webparts (also of the same reactjs app) like a weather app.

By default i defined the element id where the reactjs app should hook in.
But now i want to pass this id as parameter to the reactjs app so that i can have the app multiple times on my site.

Here is an example of what my code should lokks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="some-div">
      <div id="FirstWebPart">
        <!-- Place where the app should hook in -->
        <script src="path/to/reactjs/app.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="some-other-div">
      <div id="SecondWebPart">
        <!-- Place where the app should hook in again -->
        <script src="path/to/reactjs/app.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Important is that both apps are referencing the same source .js file but have different configs.

E.G.

The first webpart should show the weather of country 1, the second webpart should show the weather of country 2.

The logic is the same but the parameter changes the content.
Any ideas how i could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it via a function that would then instantiate the React part and connect it with the provided root element. The same function could also receive the country code.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="some-div">
      <div id="FirstWebPart">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-div">
      <div id="SecondWebPart">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="path/to/reactjs/app.js"></script>
    <script>
      myapp(document.getElementById("FirstWebPart"), "ZA");
      myapp(document.getElementById("SecondWebPart"), "BR");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure if "webpart" refers to ASP.NET, but I didn't see any "ASP.NET" tag on your question.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question correctly, you need to create 2 react components: root, child. pass the country and weather from root to child

root:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import Child from './Child'; 

const root = () => {
    const arr = [{country: 'US', weather: 'sunny'}, {country: 'UK', weather: 'rainy'}]; 
    return <body>
        {arr.map( a=><Child country={a.country} weather={a.weather} /> )}
     </body>
}
export default root;
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react'; 
const Child = (props)=> {
    return <div class="some-div">
      <div id={props.country}>
          <span>{props.weather}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
}
export default Child;
```